# angular.js:12783 Error: Could not resolve '....' from state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm a beginner in AngularJS and trying to get my head around ui-router and states. I'm working in a dashboard project in which the dashboard page has two versions 1)Student and 2)Corporate. Student version has a playful theme while the corporate has a more-corporate styling. Also some of the corporate features are hidden in the student version, mainly the sidemenu bar which is only present in corporate. By code, both the versions are rendered from the same page..dashboard.html and dashboard.js. I have hidden the student version from corporate in the dashboard.html by using `ng-if`, `ng-class` and `ng-show`.  Like this.. `ng-show="Student"`, `ng-show="corporate"`..etc. I have maintained styling of the versions by applying `student` and `corporate` class to `<body>` tag. 
Now the challenge I'm facing is, I want to be able to switch between these two versions by a dropdown menu. In the dropdown menu if user clicks student, the student version page is shown and if clicked corporate, the corporate version comes up. This is the code that does it.

```
$scope.$watch('$root.studentUser', function() {
    if ($rootScope.studentUser == undefined) {
        $scope.Student = user.student;
    } else {
        $scope.Student = $rootScope.studentUser;
    }
    if ($scope.Student) {
        $("body").removeClass("corporate").addClass("student");
    } else {
        $("body").removeClass("student").addClass("corporate");
    }
});
```

This code is working fine and I'm able to switch between the two versions. However I know i'm missing something because now the sidemenu in corporate version is not working and throwing error `angular.js:12783 Error: Could not resolve '...' from state`. Also some of the data is not getting reloaded properly. I think i should use `$state.go` or `$state.transition` to complete the transformation. But I cant seem to understand what needs to be done. Any Suggestions or links to reference. 
The State configuration...

```
if (user.student){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/explore");
        $stateProvider.state('explore', {
          url: "/explore",
          templateUrl: "/static/site/templates/explore.html"
        });
      } else {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
        $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
          url: "/dashboard",
          templateUrl: "/static/site/templates/dashboard.html",
        }).state('explore', {
          url: "/explore",
          templateUrl: "/static/site/templates/explore.html"
        }).state('setting', {
          url: "/setting",
          templateUrl: "/static/site/templates/setting.html",
        });
      }
```

The Select Tag is Kendo dropdown component

```
$scope.headerDropdownOpt = {
    dataSource: ds,
    valueTemplate: user.is_student? currentUser.userName : currentUser.name,
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    select: function(e){
        var value = this.dataItem(e.item.index()).value;
        if (value == "profile") {
            __gah_select_profile_option(value);
            $state.go('profile');
        } else if (value == "admin") {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                user.is_student = false;
                $rootScope.studentUser = user.is_student;
                // Replace Admin View to Student View
                ds.splice(ds.length-2,1,{text: $scope.student_view, value: "student"});
            });
        } else if (value == "student") {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                user.is_student = true;
                $rootScope.studentUser = user.is_student;
                // Replace Student View to Admin View
                ds.splice(ds.length-2,1,{text: $scope.normal_view, value: "admin"});
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the `select_tag` and `state configuration`

Comment: try `$state.go('explore')` under this  `$scope.Student = user.student;` line

Comment: @Sravan: it is the same, no effect

Comment: "This code is working fine and I'm able to switch between the two versions", you said that its working, is it really working?

Comment: yes..what i mean is the sidemenu links are not working..but the switching between themes is happening..it showing same error while clicking on the links